# uiviewcontroller in nib file

Tags: ios

i was studying uiviewcontroller apple guide in which it says two approaches for uiviewcontroller one of the approach allow to store uiviewcontroller to store in nib file by dragging dropping viewcontroller object ... but i didn't understand that after dragging dropping it what to do next with it should i create new `UIVC class and refer to that object i dragged dropped in nib file??

we already do that normally create UIVC class and assign to nib file owner.

this is confusing me please help.

thanks in advance and please ignore any silly mistakes if u found in this question i am a newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could put your view controller in the nib.

1. Start with an empty nib (XIB).
2. Select the File's Owner placeholder in your nib.  In the Identity Inspector, set the class of File's Owner to your application delegate class (probably `AppDelegate` or something similar).
3. Drag and drop a `UIWindow` into your nib.  Connect the `window` outlet of File's Owner to this window object.
4. Create your `UIViewController` subclass.  Let's call it `HazelViewController`.
5. Drag and drop a `UIViewController` into your nib file.  In the Identity Inspector, set the custom class of this object to `HazelViewController`.
6. Connect the `rootViewController` outlet of the window object to the `HazelViewController` object.
7. Drag and drop a `UIView` onto the window object in your nib.  Connect the `view` outlet of `HazelViewController` to this view.
8. Drop other user interface objects onto this view.  Connect them to outlets or actions of the `HazelViewController` object as necessary.
9. In the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of `AppDelegate`, load the nib, using the `AppDelegate` object as the file's owner:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options {
       [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myNib" owner:self options:nil];
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
       return YES;
   }
   ```

Comment: step 3 require adding "IBOutlet" to window preperty declaration in AppDelegate.h Otherwise it will not appear in in the list of FileOwner outlets.

Comment: another remark: it will show window without any UIViewController and UIView at all (Steps 4-8)